# Why are POST requests from EC2 to EC2 arrive from public IPs?

Tags: node.js, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

I was surprised to see that a POST request from my EC2 node.js server addressed to another node.js instance on AWS (aimed at the private IP) arrived from a Node I's public IP, not the private one.

Both public and private IP of the target instance are not available publicly; I had to create a permission, so it seems like it's working as it should.

Still, why are the requests arriving from public, not private EC2 IP addresses and is it any cause for concern?

Comment: Are the instances in same region?

Comment: Yes, they're both in the same region

Comment: There are lot of information missing. Are they in the same VPC? same subnet? Can the first instance reach the second instance by using second instance's ip?